# Angular 2: How to make <li> tag to work with key events without Jquery

Tags: html, list, html-select, key-events

I have a dropdown like this

```
<ul>
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of users"></li>
</ul>
```

How to make this to work with key events(top arrow and down arrow) without Jquery?
I need li to work like select. How do I do this?

Comment: This Might help. Not Tried http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/eventhandlers/keyboardevents/

Comment: @JayDave That's for input and I want it for li tag

Comment: can u please put some code to track .. other might also help

Comment: @JayDave My requirement is that I need li tag with dropdown to work like select tag. Is that possible without using Jqurey?